# can "using namespace std;" and "std::cout" be used together?

Tags: c++, std, name-lookup, using-directives

No an error occurs when using `using namespace std;` and `std::cout`  together. Can these two be used together?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    std::cout << "Hello world!";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes you can, but why would you want to?

Comment: Why do you think they can't be used together?

Comment: Better yet, `std::cout` can be used without `using namespace std;` which is the preferred method.

Comment: @AlanBirtles because they both mean the same..

Comment: They can be used together because they both mean the same.

Answer (score 5):

There is no problem. In this statement

```
std::cout << "Hello world!";
```

there is used the qualified name lookup of the name `cout` in the namespace `std`.

You could also write

```
cout << "Hello world!";
```

and in this case there would be used the unqualified name lookup and the name `cout` would be found due to the directive

```
using namespace std;
```

You could also include the using declaration like

```
using std::cout;
```

Pay attention to that you should avoid to use the using directive. It can be a reason of ambiguity. It is much better to use qualified names.

Comment: @Eljay using namespace is a using directive. So your comment is unclear.

Comment: @Eljay I think Vlad's remark about your comment being unclear is due to you seemingly confusing the terminology of different usage of the [`using` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/using): as explained in the article about [Namespaces](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) on Cppreference, one is called _using-**directive**_ (see #5, à la `using namespace std;`), the other is called _using-**declaration**_ (see #6, à la `using std::cout;`). So, as Vlad says in his answer, we should avoid using the using-**directive** and prefer using the using-**declaration**.

Comment: @heapunderrun • thanks, that explains!

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `namespace` is to protect against collision. When you type in `using namespace std;` it turns off that protection. This lets you use `cout`, `string`, `vector`... without `std::` resolution, but they may collide with other namespaces.

In some tutorials you may see `using namespace std;` They put that in there to make the examples shorter without having to type in `std::` every where. But that usage is limited to short examples. For actual code it is recommended not to add `using namespace std;`

You can always use `std::cout`, `std::string`, `std::vector` etc. without worrying about collision.